# How do I remove an array from a string?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code

```
location: '["41.8481","-72.0345"]'
```

Here is what I tried

```
location.replace(/'/g,'');
```

This is what I want

```
location: ["41.8481","-72.0345"]
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: You want to convert the string to an array?

Comment: I want this location: ["41.8481","-72.0345"]

Comment: Got it check my answer below, it has a working snippet as well!

Answer (score 2):

##### You can parse the string to an array using [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

```js
const loc = '["41.8481","-72.0345"]';
const locArr = JSON.parse(loc);
console.log(locArr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can parse to get the desired solution

> `JSON.parse(location)`

Comment: Thank you! Someone updated their answer to match yours, but I know who helped me.

Comment: Make it to green if its right... It would help others... Cheers!